# Can I use an external WIFI adapter with my Android Head unit

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

I purchased the [Pumpkin 2 Din Universal Car Head Unit](http://www.autopumpkin.com/2-din-universal-car-dvd-gps-navigation-pure-android-4-4-stereo-head-unit-with-6-95-inch-lcd-hd-capacitive-touch-screen-3g-wifi-bluetooth-obd2-free-mic.html) (see product image below) and I want to know if I can use an external long range WIFI adapter via one of the USB/3g ports on the back? The device runs Android 4.4 and has built-in support for 3G and WIFI already. Device specs say "Can't support portable hard drive" – but that doesn't necessarily mean no OTG support I guess.

[image: Pumpkin 2]

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a manual for the unit (the website doesn't properly link to the "Manual&Download" section from the header, and the "Support Center" link doesn't do anything at all), and since it doesn't mention anything about a WiFi antenna adapter, it's hard to say one way or another with any level of confidence.

That said, it may be possible.  It seems to contradict itself in a couple of places referring to a "WiFi/3G/Mic Cable" before later calling it a "3G/USB Cable+Mic Cable".  The "3G" actually requires an external modem to function, so I'm guessing it's just two USB ports.  It will probably accept a USB WiFi device, but it's questionable if the OS will support the hardware.  It does have a built-in WiFi modem, but I'm not aware of any USB antennae designed to connect to a separate device.

NOTE: IF YOU FOLLOW THE SUGGESTIONS BELOW, IT MAY A. VOID YOUR WARRANTY AND B. BRICK/RUIN YOUR DEVICE. PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK, I ACCEPT NO RESPONSIBILITY

If you were to open up the case, it may be possible to find a place to connect an antenna to that built-in adapter.  If that's the case, you can probably get an extension cable that would let you then place a long-range antenna somewhere more appropriate.  I know my Samsung Galaxy S4 has two little connectors for external antennas, but I don't think either is for WiFi.

Comment: As the device seems to support a WiFi hotspot, an alternative might be to use some other device as "bridge" – though that might be a little overkill ;)